# Find where Python function is called in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way for PyCharm to show where a given Python function is called from?

I currently rely on simply searching for the function name across the project and this often works fine, but if a function name is vague there are a lot of incorrect hits. I'm wondering if I'm missing a feature somewhere, e.g. perhaps the search results could be further narrowed down to only show where modules import the module I'm searching from?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In PyCharm you can select a function and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to run a usage search. It's also available under "Edit → Find → Find Usages". It looks like it's more intelligent than a text search.

Using static analysis to find where a function is called from is difficult in general in Python because it uses dynamic binding and has a lot of introspection so it's very easy to get false positives miss usages.  In the case of module-level functions I think a good solution is to always use `module.function` to call the function and never do a `from module import function`.  That way you can do a text search for 'module.function'.  Python style guides generally recommend that you import functions etc. in this way so I think this is generally accepted good practice.

Finding method calls is of course much harder.  One of the things I like about developing in Java and C# is being able to find all usages of a method by static analysis.

Comment: That looks to be exactly the feature I was looking for, thank you. I often use `import as` to make the namespaces more manageable but the downside is that searching becomes even trickier.

Comment: In subsequent versions of PyCharm, the "Find Usages" binding has changed to `<Alt-Shift-F7>`. For some reason, but mostly just because. Failing that, this menu item now lives at "Edit → Find → Find Usages". Why read-only "Find" operations would live under the top-level "Edit" rather than "View" or "Navigate" menus is anyone's worst guess. (_I've got nuthin'._)

Answer (score 9):

Press the Ctrl key and simultaneously hover your mouse over the function header.The function name should get highlighted.Click on the function name to get a list of all instances where the function is called.

If you press the Ctrl key and simultaneously  hover your mouse over a function call, then the function name will be highlighted and clicking on it will take you to the function definition.